# Installing NetBeans 8.0.2 with JDK 9.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans

When I try to install NetBeans 8.0.2 on my PC (Win10-64bit) I get the error message:

[image]

despite that I already installed JDK 9.0.1, as evident in the command prompt:

[image]

My path variables are set as follows:

[image]

Comment: post screenshot of error

Comment: @Ravi- Done, see edit.

Comment: I'm assuming you are facing this problem while installation not while launching application.

Comment: Correct, as soon as I klick on the downloaded NetBeans exe-file.

Comment: uninstall java from the system and install again, and also where are your other environment path variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Netbeans which supports JDK 9 is yet to [release](https://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1645.html) (i.e, Netbeans 9.0 which is in development mode).

And the documentation states this.

> By: jkovalsky, 09 Oct 2017
>
> If you have downloaded JDK 9 recently and try to convince your NetBeans 8.2 IDE to run on top of it we will probably disappoint you, because 8.2 version is not designed to work with JDK 9.
>
> In order to use JDK 9 happily you will need to download a NetBeans 9.0 development build from Apache Incubator. For more information please read Geertjan Wielenga's post on Using Apache NetBeans IDE.
>
> Thank you!
> NetBeans team

I've also faced the same issue with **Netbeans 8.2** (but you're trying with **Netbeans 8.0.2**). So, I installed JDK 8 and the Netbeans installation went fine.

Still if you want to use JDK 9 you can install it alongside with JDK 8. But you need to set JDK path as JDK 8 in the system path (like you did for JDK 9). While installing Netbeans select JDK 8 installation path as JDK for Netbeans.

I hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you are getting error when trying to install NetBeans, in that case you can specify the JDK at command line

```
<netbeans_installer>.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0"
```

**[FaqSuitableJvmNotFound](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSuitableJvmNotFound)**

Comment: open command prompt from the folder where you kept your netbeans installer and execute above command. Make sure JDK path is correctly specified

Comment: I keep the file in downloads. From that map, i just copied that line. but should it not be jdk9.0.1 ??

C:\Users\Lenovo>cd Downloads

C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads><netbeans_installer>.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads>

Comment: `<netbeans_installer>` is an example, how would I know what is the installer name ? you haven't shared it. Haven't you installed anything earlier  on your system ?

Comment: Also, I clearly mentioned, **Make sure JDK path is correctly specified**

Comment: Installer name: netbeans-8.2-windows
JDK Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1

Still says cannot find specified file in CMD.

Comment: I had JGrasp earlier with same JDK, but I now want to switch to Netbeans.