# Netbeans does not detect JDK installation

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have installed Netbeans 8.0.2 and it doesn't find the JDK installation path.

I suppose I have done all the steps correctly. Netbeans insists that I haven't installed the JDK.

How can I solve this issue?

[[image]

Comment: JavaScript is unrelated to Java. What JDK did you install? Note that netbeans 8 is **old**. Also, the message about needing Java 7 or greater was written well before they decided to break things in Java 9. So **believe** the message. And install a ***compatible*** JDK ASAP. Which is probably Java 7. Which is not readily available or supported any more.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What's your operation system?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967336/installing-netbeans-8-0-2-with-jdk-9-0-1

Answer (score 1):

This error exists because, you haven't configured the Environment Variable on your PC, that's why NetBeans is not detecting it. I recommend you to check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation).

Or you may Uninstall/Delete the existing NetBeans and JDK installer and download and install from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html). It has package already linked with JDK, so you don't have to configure it later.